# collectFirst: Applying partial function with multiple case clauses

Tags: scala, partialfunction

So I have defined a partial function to be used for collectFirst method in collection:

```
myList.collectFirst{
  case A(_,_,_) => ....
  case B(_,_,_) => ....
  case C(_,_,_) => ....
}
```

If myList contains A,B,C all then which case would be executed?

Comment: PartialFunction matches with top down order and stops at the first match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `collectFirst` said the following:

> Finds the first element of the collection for which the given partial function is defined, and applies the partial function to it.

Let's assume `val myList = List(A(...), B(...), C(...))`.
In that case `case A(_, _, _)` will be executed.
If we have `val myList = List(B(...), A(...), C(...))` then the second case will be executed because `B(...)` is the first element satisfied the partial fucntion.